# Modify html file in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, webview

I put the following code into the xml file of the layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F0E68C"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/heading"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ATTENDANCE STATS"
        android:textSize="35dp" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="click me!"
        ></Button>
 </LinearLayout>
```

the webview displays a html file called table.html. Idid this in the java file of the activity as follows :

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/table.html");
```

Now, I want to modify this html file from the java class of the activity, before loading it. How can I do this?

Comment: You do not able write any thing in android asset folder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read HTML file from assets.
2. Modify the HTML data in your app.
3. Load the modified data to `WebView` with [`loadData()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadData%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) (or `loadDataWithBaseURL()`) instead of `loadUrl()`.

Comment: you can not modify files from assets.

Comment: @KeshavSonni That's true and that's why you do the modification in memory, loading the data from a string rather than a URL.